# Selenium python, use css to select only two class

Tags: python, css, selenium, class, classname

Suppose I have an HTML that looks like this:

```
<div class="first second">
    Right!
</div>
<div class="first second third fourth">
    Wrong!
</div>
<div class="first second">
    Right!
</div>
```

If I try to locate the first and third div, using css:

```
driver.find_elements_by_class_name("first, second")
```

Instead of getting 2 elements in my list, I get all the three divs because the second one actually contains those classes and some others... How can I restrict it, to locate only the `<div>`s with:

```
class = "first second"
```

Comment: what is the tag you have that contains `first, second` third tag also contains the same thing.

Comment: You can't use the Xpath?

Answer (score 1):

```
div[class = 'first second']
```

should work. Cause it is a exact match.

use it with `CSS_SELECTOR`

```
driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR , "div[class = 'first second']")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this if you need to get them via xpath:

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath(".//div[@class='first second']")
```